# Correctly build and import a custom library

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

I'm building my own library of useful functions I use between projects. For this I've decided to create a private NPM packages `@name/package`.

The problem comes when I try to import it in my `CRA` application. The server compiles correctly (in the CLI) but upon visiting the page it gives me the `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function` error. I use babel for compiling using the config below.

**Babel config**

```
{
    presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"]
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./src/index.js",
  "files": [
    "src/**/*",
    "dist/**/*"
  ],
}
```

---

**src/index.js**

```
export { default as mapObject} from "./mapObject";
```

**src/mapObject.js**

```
export default function mapObject(object, callback) {
    return Object.keys(object || {}).map(key => callback(key, object[key]));
}
```

---

**dist/index.js (compiled by babel)**

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

Object.defineProperty(exports, "mapObject", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _mapObject.default;
  }
});

var _mapObject = _interopRequireDefault(require("./mapObject"));
```

**dist/mapObject.js**

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = mapObject;

function mapObject(object, callback) {
  return Object.keys(object || {}).map(function (key) {
    return callback(key, object[key]);
  });
}
```

---

**Importing the file**

```
// Causes error when loading in the browser
import { mapObject } from "@name/package";
import { mapObject } from "@name/package/src";
import { mapObject } from "@name/package/dist";

// Doesn't cause an error
import mapObject from "@name/package/dist/mapObject";
import mapObject from "@name/package/src/mapObject";
```

I've checked multiple other libraries and to me there are no differences in the build/import process.

Answer (score 0):

So the above shown code is actually correct but I messed up when I was testing it by not copying over the new src and dist folders...